# Vba Getpivotdata wrong syntax

Tags: excel, syntax, vba

i just want to iterate throught a pivot table. I am using getpivotdata to extract the pivot values. However, i must doing something wrong with syntax, because getpivotdata cannot work. I know that the problem is there because using values straigth from the pivot, makes it work.

I tried single quotes, double quotes, nothing helped. Please, can anyone check what is wrong with the getpivotdata syntax?

I

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim rsl As PivotTable
Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet3").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Dim counter As Integer



For Each customer In pt.RowFields("ccode").PivotItems
  For Each product In pt.RowFields("pcode").PivotItems
   For Each size In pt.RowFields("psize").PivotItems

       Range("D1") = pt.GetPivotData("quantity", "Customer Name", customer, "Product Name", product, "Product size", size)



   Next
 Next
Next



 End Sub
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the field names you use in the `GetPivotData` call match the fields you are looping through.

Comment: These are not the original fields. So this is not a problem